# Pandas Merging Dataframes One with Different Time Stamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, timestamp

Suppose we have two dataframes, one with a timestamp and the other with start and end timestamps. df1 and df2 as:

| DateTime | Value1 | StartDateTime | EnddDateTime | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-11 12:30:00 | 1 | 2020-01-11 12:23:12 | 2020-01-11 13:10:00 | a |
| 2020-01-11 13:00:00 | 2 | 2020-01-11 14:12:20 | 2020-01-11 14:20:34 | b |
| 2020-02-11 13:30:00 | 3 | 2020-01-11 15:20:00 | 2020-01-11 15:28:10 | c |
| 2020-02-11 14:00:00 | 4 | 2020-01-11 15:45:20 | 2020-01-11 16:26:23 | d |
| 2020-02-11 14:30:00 | 5 |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-11 15:00:00 | 6 |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-11 15:30:00 | 7 |  |  |  |
| 2020-02-11 16:00:00 | 8 |  |  |  |

The timestamp of df1 represents half an hour starting from the time in the `DateTime` column. I want to match df2 start and end time with these 20 minutes periods. A value of df2 may fall in two rows of df1 if its period (the time between start and end) matches with two `DateTime` in df1, even for only one second. The outcome should be a dataframe as below.

| DateTime | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-11 12:30:00 | 1 | a |
| 2020-01-11 13:00:00 | 2 | a |
| 2020-02-11 13:30:00 | 3 | Nan |
| 2020-02-11 14:00:00 | 4 | b |
| 2020-02-11 14:30:00 | 5 | Nan |
| 2020-02-11 15:00:00 | 6 | c |
| 2020-02-11 15:30:00 | 7 | d |
| 2020-02-11 16:00:00 | 8 | d |

Any suggestions to efficiently merge large data?

Comment: do you mind sharing the dataframes as a dictionary? ``df.to_dict('records')``

Answer (score 1):

There maybe shorter better answers out there because I am going longhand.

melt the second data frame

```
df3=pd.melt(df2, id_vars=['Value2'], value_vars=['StartDateTime', 'EnddDateTime'],value_name='DateTime').sort_values(by='DateTime')
```

Create temp columns on both dfs. The reason is, you want to get the time from datetime, append that time to a uniform date to be used in the merge

```
df1['DateTime1']=pd.Timestamp('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' ' +pd.to_datetime(df1['DateTime']).dt.time.astype(str)
df3['DateTime1']=pd.Timestamp('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + ' ' +pd.to_datetime(df3['DateTime']).dt.time.astype(str)
```

Convert the new column date times computed above to datetime

```
df3["DateTime1"]=pd.to_datetime(df3["DateTime1"])
df1["DateTime1"]=pd.to_datetime(df1["DateTime1"])
```

Finally, mergeasof with a time tolerance

```
   final = pd.merge_asof(df1, df3, on="DateTime1",tolerance=pd.Timedelta("39M"),suffixes=('_', '_df2')).drop(columns=['DateTime1','variable','DateTime_df2'])

              DateTime_  Value1 Value2
0  2020-01-11 13:00:00       2      a
1  2020-02-11 13:30:00       3      a
2  2020-02-11 14:00:00       4    NaN
3  2020-02-11 14:30:00       5      b
4  2020-02-11 15:00:00       6    NaN
5  2020-02-11 15:30:00       7      c
6  2020-02-11 16:00:00       8      d
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer. The problem with melting the second data frame is that if the duration of a row (the time between start and end) covers three or more rows in df1, then the middle rows will be NaN. For example, if the `EndDatTime` of the first row in df2 were 13:40, the code would generate `a`, `NaN` and `a` for rows 0, 1 and 2 of df1, while it should be all `a`s.